# PHP to read secured file

Tags: php, xml

I have a xml-file on subdomain a, and a php script on subdomain b. I want to read, and use, the data from the XML file, through PHP.

Here's the catch. The file is secured using HTTP Authentication.

How do I make PHP log-in, and read the contents of the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [url wrappers](http://us.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php) support URLs of the form `http://USER:PASS@yourdomain.com/foo/bar` so you could simply use [file_get_contents](http://php.net/file_get_contents).

Alternatively, you could fetch it with [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/), either shelling out to use a curl command line, or using the [curl extension](http://php.net/curl). Failing that, you could hand code the request using fsockopen etc. [Basic authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) is called Basic for a reason - it's trivially easy to implement: [here's one user-submitted example in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php#32830).

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need the advanced versions of cURL (which is less necessary these days IMO) you can just start the filename with 'http://user:password@example.com' whereever you read the XML file and it should work pretty transparently.  It will use a blocking connection, so your script will pause while it waits for a response.

```
$xdocument = simplexml_load_file('http://user:password@subdomain.example.com/thexmlfile.xml');
```

Comment: for some reason it doesn't seem to be loading the document,
while the previously suggested 'file_get_contents' does

thx anyways :)