# load xml file with authentication (and improving security)

Tags: php, http, authentication, simplexml

I'm trying to use simplexml to load an xml file from a server:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($xml_query);
```

The server needs HTTP authentication, so (unsurprisingly) I get an error message:

> HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 401
>   Unauthorized

Is it possible to pass my username and password to the server using this function?

**EDIT**

If anyone can tell me a more secure way to do this, I'd be grateful.

Comment: dup : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/564682/php-to-read-secured-file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to prepend the username and password to the URL you're opening. Instead of

```
http://link.to/file.xml
```

try

```
http://username:password@link.to/file.xml
```

Comment: @Tomba be aware that you are sending your username and password in cleartext this way and is easily sniffed by a Man-in-the-Middle.

Comment: very true - i always assume people know the security implications of doing this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

This is my first attempt at making it more secure, using cURL:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $xml_query);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ':' . $password);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$xml = simplexml_load_string($result);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not any more secure. You are still subject to MitM attacks because all that's changed is that you're sending the HTTP request through cURL. The request is identical otherwise; you can confirm this with a packet sniffer. Basic authentication is basic authentication. The only real way to lock it down is to use HTTPS. But if you normally access this resource through HTTP then maybe the remote host is not concerned with encryption and you shouldn't worry about it.

Comment: OK, thanks. It sounds like I need to work out how to do it using HTTPS.